# How do I batch update a field with a function in Django

Tags: django, django-models

How do I batch update a field with a function in Django and The function argument is the field value . such as

```
Data.objects.filter(need_add=1).update(need_add=Myfunc(F('need_add')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `.update` does its work at the SQL query level, i.e. inside the Database engine. Unless you can encode your function in SQL, you have to fetch the objects, update them, and save them. There is `.bulk_update` [(link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) as an optimization compared to a simple iteration over a queryset saving objects one-by-one.

[Database functions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/)